# Применение интрефейсов в джава приложениях (слабая связанность)

Tags: java

Проходя бесплатный типо курс по джава и делая учебный проект у меня возникла такая проблема. Есть 3 сервисных класса `GarageSpaceService`, `OrderService`, `MasterService`. Так же есть класс `Administrator` который по моей задумке должен предоставлять API. `Administrator` содержит ссылки на сервисные классы и вот здесь заключается проблема - преподаватель пишет в замечаниях что у меня нету слабой связанности (то есть `Administrator` знает о конкретных реализациях). Я решил создать интрефейс `Service`(типо как метка) реализовать его остальными сервисами но дальше понял что так не получися ведь я не смогу обращаться к методам описанным в моих сервисах. Вот в чем заключается вопрос - правильно ли создавать на каждый сервис свой интерфейс где и описать все методы которые должен предоставлять сервис? Или же нужно поступить как-то по другому? И ещё если есть люди которые могут ответить еще на несколько вопросов учебного джава приложения дайте пожалуйста знать (преподаватель на курсах не дает ни каких конкретных ответов).

Comment: `И ещё если есть люди которые могут ответить еще на несколько вопросов` вы не сайте вопросов и ответов. Не надо искать конкретных людей. Есть вопросы - задавайте вопросами.

Comment: [Зачем придумали интерфейсы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1071261/179763)

Comment: Беда всех курсов, как и беда бизнес тренингов. Вас учат зарабатывать деньги люди которые сами не умеют зарабатывать

Comment: @AzizUmarov я бы не был так категоричен. Регулярно смотрю оналйн курсы, в том числе платные, мне очень помогает. Тут главное правило - не верить всему на слово и думать своей головой.

Comment: дело а том что курсы которые прохожу построены на самообучении. а научиться писать код правильно оказывается достаточно сложно. и когда требуют хороший код указывая только на ошибки и не давая никаких рекомендаций это огорчает. думаю может на платных курсах может учат чему-то (рассматриваю такой вариант - пойти на платные).

Comment: Артем это то да. Когда сам спец и можешь различить. Что делать тем кто сам не знает и критического мышления ещё нет? Верить на слово? Я говорю о тех кто даёт базовые понятия молодым и не опытным.

Comment: Платные или нет разница только в том что вы в праве требовать оплаченные услуги.

Comment: @AzizUmarov тот, кто ничего не знает, может курсы пройти при какой то конторе (которая для себя набирает) или также есть платные, но тут уже как повезет. Сам знаю людей, которые после платных курсов уезжали заграницу программистами, но это скорее исключение, чем правило.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что такое слабая связь? Это когда класс не знает о конкретной реализации другого класса. Как это достигается?

- Давайте рассмотрим пример сильной связи.

  ```
  ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
  strings.add("Hello");
  ```

  Вы создали переменную `ArrayList`. Все хорошо, ваш код прекрасно работает. Потом вы написали второй класс который что-то делает с вашим списком.

  ```
  class Adapter {

      public void someFunctionWithList(ArrayList<String> strings){
          // some code
      }
  }
  ```

Со временем таких классов становится намного больше, они расползаются по приложению. И тут у вас что-то изменилось в проекте и вы понимаете, что вам больше не подходит `ArrayList`, а вам нужен `LinkedList`. Что в таком случае вы будете делать? Правильно, вы начнете менять во всех местах где в качестве аргументов передает `ArrayList` на `LinkedList`, что затратно и чревато ошибками.

- Что можно сделать лучше? Вы можете абстрагироваться от конкретной реализации и использовать интерфейс. Тот же код, но со слабой связью:

  ```
  List<String> anotherStrings = new ArrayList<>();
  anotherStrings.add("Hello");
  ```

  И ваш `Adapter` (а так же все другие классы/методы):

  ```
  class Adapter {

      public void someFunctionWithList(List<String> strings){
          // some code
      }
  }
  ```

  Теперь если вам придется `ArrayList` сменить на `LinkedList` вы это сделает ТОЛЬКО в одном месте:

  ```
  List<String> anotherStrings = new LinkedList<>();
  ```

  И весь остальной код будет работать. Все клиенты ничего не знают о реализации вашего списка, им важно знать лишь одно: "Что все они реализуют интерфейс `List`".
- Еще один признак сильной связи. Допустим у вас есть класс:

  ```
  class Controller { 

      Repository repository = ProductionRepository();

      // some code
  }
  ```

  Что не так здесь, казало бы есть интерфейс, все должно быть ок? Но нет, класс `Controller` зависит от конкретной реализации `ProductionRepository` и вы не сможете его заменить а рантайме, вы не сможете подменить его для тестирования или других целей. Да конечно можно написать такой код внутри Controller:

  ```
  public Repository getRepository(){

      if(debug) return DebugRepository();
      else return ProdRepository();
  }
  ```

  И он будет работать. Но тогда ваш класс `Controller` будет знать о двух реализациях. Например в продуктовом коде у вас будет реализация `DebugRepository` хоть и не будет использоваться. А если вам нужно будет добавить еще одну реализацию, то вам придется лезть в класс и добавлять еще один `if`.
- На помощь приходит "Внедрение зависимостей" (DI - Dependency Injection).

  В самом простом виде внедрение зависимостей выглядит так:

  ```
  class Controller { 

      Repository repository;

      Controller (Repository repository){
          this.repository = repository;
      }

      // some code
  }
  ```

  Что мы имеем? А то, что наш класс `Controller` не зависит от конкретной реализации `Repository`, ему важно лишь то, чтоб входящий класс реализовывал интерфейс `Repository`. А тот факт, что передача экземпляра происходит через конструктор позволяет нам в реалтайме менять нужные нам зависимости не влезая в код класса. Мы можем запускать нужные нам объекта в разных сборках, для разных ситуаций. Например у нас есть банковское приложение для взрослых и детей и у нас есть класс который подгружает счета для. Интерфейс работы с этим классом может быть одинаков, но на детском и взрослом приложении будет разная реализация. Так же мы можем подменять нужные нам объекты для тестирования.

  Все это приправляется еще тем, что есть фреймворки DI которые позволяют задавать реализации только в одном месте на весь проект, и в случае потребности замены, вы меняете их только в 1 месте и а весь проект.
- Что касается вопроса: *"Нужно ли для всего писать интерфейс?"*. Нет конечно, как говорилось в одном фильме: *"Только ситхи все возводят в абсолют"*. Писать интерфейс на все глупо и не нужно. Вам нужно анализировать класс. Если ваш класс может иметь разные реализации или потенциально вы захотите эту реализацию подменить, то пишите интерфейс. Если же вы понимаете, что этот класс будет использоваться только так и никак иначе, то не пишите. Серебряной пули тут нет, никто вам не скажет правила по которому можно всегда следовать. Это приходит с опытом.

  Так же нужно понимать, что не все параметры нужно передавать через конструктор. Если вы реализуете к примеру свой `Stack` то вам совершенно не обязательно прокидывать через конструктор структуру данных на базе которой будет организован ваш стек. Но если вы пишите класс для работы с сетевыми запросами, то очевидно, что протокол через который будет это все происходить должен иметь слабую связь.