# Немного не понимаю момент с Интерфейсом!

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, заранее спасибо каждому <3. Так вот, в интерфейсах часто (Если не всегда) к переменным прибавляют {get; set;} как я понял это значит что можно ЧИТАТЬ и ПЕРЕПИСЫВАТЬ значения, но вот я не понимаю зачем это делать если вроде как интерфейс это абстракция. Кто-то делал через интерфейс и Scriptable Objects инвентарь и сделали примерно так

Первый скрипт с интерфейсом

```
IItems
{ 
    string name {get;} 
    `И другие переменные`
}
```

Потом он в другой скрипт который прикреплён к Scriptable Objects присвоил значения к интерфейсу вот так

```
Scriptable Objects, IItems
{
    public string mame => _name; //реализация
    [SerializedField]private string _name; //для редактирования значения параметра в СкрОбъект
}
```

Так вот, нафига это всё сделано, для чего здесь используется интерфейс, почему нельзя без него просто только с [Serialized Field] и потом просто обратится к этому СкриптОбъекту и уже с ним взаимодействовать. Та и ещё одно, куда девается(Как можно присвоить что-то абстракции) то что выделил

> Scriptable Objects, IItems{**public string name** => _name;
> [Serialized Field]private string _name;}

Как можно к этом обратится

Comment: Этот код невалидный, вы плохо его скопировали

Comment: Про интерфейсы вначале почитайте https://habr.com/ru/post/343852/

Comment: aepot это не код (Это пример) для того что бы понять логику происходящего в целом

Comment: Похоже, вам нужно объяснение, в чём разница между полями и свойствами. Это не имеет прямого отношения к интерфейсам.

Comment: `get` и `set` это [свойства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/197075), у них да, можно указать что они будут только отдавать данные, или наоборот, только их получать. Интерфейс - это контракт, который обязательно должен соблюсти тот, кто его реализует. Если в интерфейсе указано свойство с `get` и `set`, то это означает то, что тот, кто будет это реализовывать, обязан будет иметь у себя такое свойство, с таким названием, и с `get; set;`. Если в интерфейсе указан, например только `get`, то в реализующем классе также должен быть обязательно только `get`, а `set` уже на его усмотрение.

Comment: Зачем интерфейсы? Скажем так, интерфейс, это когда вам без разницы кто и что там реализовал, и как, важно только то, чтоб на выходе был конечный результат. Допустим вот инвентарь, в нем хранятся предметы, предметы могут быть разные, с разной логикой, допустим квестовый, расходник, броня, оружие. Каждый предмет имеет свою реализацию, свой код, на который инвентарю, по сути, без разницы, ибо ему нужно лишь название, тип, кол-во. Вот вы и делаете интерфейс, который будет содержать в себе нечто связывающее все предметы, делаете коллекцию интерфейса, реализуете интерфейс у нужных классов, готово.

Comment: у вас тут 2 вопроса: 1) зачем нужны get/set (то есть свойства) 2) зачем нужны интерфейсы. На первый вопрос ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/197075/179763), на второй вопрос можно почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1071299/179763)

Comment: ВСЕМ ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО, Я МНОГО ЧЕГО ПОНЯЛ СЕЙЧАС <3