# Современные интерфейсы

Tags: c#

Есть какое то видео или текст на `RU` объясняющий `современные интерфейсы` с реализацией `private`, `static` членов у которых обязана быть реализация в самих интерфейсах ?

Пытался искать в `Google`, все разъясняют использование интерфейсов с публичными членами, называя интерфейсы "публичным контрактом" с классом, где у экземпляров класса реализующего интерфейс, все члены интерфейса должны быть доступны на экземпляре класса.

Хотя смотрю тот же `MSDN`, члены интерфейсов могут иметь различные модификаторы доступа, да ещё private и static обязаны иметь реализацию.

Просто только по `MSDN` сложно разобраться для чего `Microsoft` добавил новые возможности интерфейсам + нюансы машинного перевода.

А на `YouTube` и `Google`, говорят спорная фича и т.п.

Comment: [зачем придумали интерфейсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1071299/179763)?

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо! Здорово разъяснили необходимость интерфейсов. А для чего понадобились приватные и статические члены с реализацией в интерфейсах ?

Comment: Видимо, решили прокачать интерфейсы имплементацией по умолчанию (я не пишу на дотнете, потому могу быть неточен), а там где есть имплементация, там и сразу нужны и уровни доступа к имплементации и прочие фишки. Сути интерфейсов это не меняет, я лично к этому как сахару отношусь - то есть какие то фишки упрощающие код, но не меняющие саму концепцию интерфейсов.

Comment: "нюансы машинного перевода" - учите всё-таки английский и читайте документацию в оригинале, это не так уж сложно, на самом деле. Действительно, русский перевод у Микрософта часто хромает, иной раз невозможно понять, что они вообще хотели сказать.